# How to use an AND statement with ARRAYFORMULA when searching a range in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this function which works great.

```
=transpose
(
    split
    (
        ARRAYFORMULA
        (
            TEXTJOIN
            (
                ", ",TRUE,
                (
                    IF
                    (
                        A3:A100="Active",
                        B3:B100
                        ,""
                    )
                )
            )
        ),","
    )
)
```

It says if Anything Between A3 and A100 is the word Active, then Display B3 in a vertical list.

---

I am trying to query multiple parameters though and am hitting dead ends. When I try to add an AND statement to the IF query, I get no results. Example:

```
=transpose
(
    split
    (
        ARRAYFORMULA
        (
            TEXTJOIN
            (
                ", ",TRUE,
                (
                    IF
                    (
                        AND(A3:A100="Active", C3:C100="Sold"),
                        B3:B100
                        ,""
                    )
                )
            )
        ),","
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not supported. use multiplication:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 IF((A3:A100="Active")*(C3:C100="Sold"), B3:B100, ))), ","))
```

Comment: Awesome! I did not know this was a thing. I will research to understand why this works. Thank you.

Comment: If AND is Multiplication does that make OR Division?

Comment: @KevinWeber `*` for `AND` & `+` for `OR`